# macro keystrokes via input file?

Tags: macros, keystrokes

I am thinking of writing one up but i'll ask first.

Are there any apps that will do keystrokes to an application via an input file? i have a list of 1400 keystrokes i need to do. Basically its 4 numbers a right click, down arrow a few times and enter. I generated the input file so i can easily regenerate it in a way the macro app wants. What app can i use?

Comment: Which Operating System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in Windows you should be able to create an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script that incorporates your keystrokes.

Plus, assign a hotkey, watch for events like a specific window being opened, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For BSD/Linux [Xnee](http://www.gnu.org/software/xnee/) will do that.